# Woocommerce product price change

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am a PHP novice, not good with code at all. I am using this plugin eForm (https://eform.live/) that generates a woocommerce product based on the user's choices. I need the generated product not to exceed $100, but show the actual price if it's below $100. I looked up & found the following code which does what I want partly, but this code always shows the price at $100 even if the actual product price is below $100. I'm looking for help from someone to figure this out. Thanks!

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post, $blog_id;
    $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price');
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if ($price > 100){
    $updatedprice = 100;
    }
    return $updatedprice;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    $price = $product->get_regular_price();
    if($price > 100){
        $updatedprice = 100;
    }else{
        $updatedprice = $price;
    }
    return $updatedprice;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, the product price is always 0 after adding this code